# iOS - UITableView Updating After Display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have a view set up with two tables. This view gets data loaded into it on a regular basis, and I want the first table to be the height necessary to display all of the items so that the table doesn't have to scroll. I have the following code to accomplish this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   table1.frame = CGRectMake(table1.frame.origin.x, table1.frame.origin.y, table1.frame.size.width, tableHeight1);
   table2.frame = CGRectMake(table2.frame.origin.x, table1.frame.origin.y + 20 + tableHeight1, table2.frame.size.width, tableHeight2);
    if(tableHeight2 + table2.frame.origin.y  > 550){
        tableHeight2 = 530 - table2.frame.origin.y;
    }
    table1.frame = CGRectMake(table1.frame.origin.x, table1.frame.origin.y, table1.frame.size.width, tableHeight1);
    table2.frame = CGRectMake(table2.frame.origin.x, table1.frame.origin.y + 25 + tableHeight1, table2.frame.size.width, tableHeight2);

}
```

It works. When everything is said and done, the first table is sized accordingly and so is the second table under it.

The problem comes in that the view first loads size of the table as it is laid out in the storyboard, then once everything is done it adjusts the size accordingly. So the user sees either a partial table or a half-blank table for two seconds before it resizes to the appropriate height.

I've tried pasting the code into viewDidLoad, into layoutSubviews, and it either breaks or does not resize the table at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried that, it does not resize the table at all then. Same as the others. Unless I need different code for it to work?

Comment: I saw another answer that said I have to make the tables programatically. Could that be it?

Comment: If you paste the code in multiple places (viewWillAppear,  etc.), will it work better? I think you need to find out why the UI will update after two seconds. Are you loading some data?

Comment: I am loading data. Is there something I can do to load the data and update the table before anything shows up?

Comment: Yes that should be in viewWillAppear. Where are you calling reloadData?

Comment: If I put it in viewWillAppear, the table doesn't get resized. I tried reloading the data above the code and below, I get the same result.

Comment: When are tableHeight1 and tableHeight2 updated?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a table view to appear, already at the right size you could try adding it to your view programatically i.e.

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; //your custom frame
```

more code involved but also more control.